# Derive a formula to successively decrement a given value by $x\%$ $n$ times

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages, derivation-of-formulae

I have a value where it needs to be decremented by $x\%$ successively $n$ times

For example, for

$$\begin{align*}
\text{value} &= 100 \\
x &= 2\% \\
n &= 3 \end{align*}$$

we expect the value $94.1192$ because

$$\begin{align*}
100 - (\text{$2\%$ of 100}) &= 98\\
98 - (\text{$2\%$ of 98}) &= 96.04\\
96.04 - (\text{$2\%$ of 96.04}) &= 94.1192 \end{align*}$$

I am looking for a formula that can accomplish the goal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formula for consecutively subtracting a percentage n times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4159779/formula-for-consecutively-subtracting-a-percentage-n-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what it means to take $p\%$ off of an initial value $v_0$ to form a new value $v_1$:

$$v_1 = v_0 - (\text{$p\%$ of $v$}) = v_0 - \frac{p}{100} v_0 = \frac{100-p}{100} v_0$$

Take $p\%$ off of this again to form $v_2$:

$$v_2 = v_1 - (\text{$p\%$ of $v_1$}) = v_1 - \frac{p}{100} v_1 = \frac{100-p}{100} v_1$$

But then, we know $v_1$ in terms of just $v_0$:

$$v_2 = \frac{100-p}{100} \frac{100-p}{100} v_0 = \left( \frac{100-p}{100} \right)^2 v_0$$

Try this again and see if you can convince yourself of a pattern that gives $v_n$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another direction:

Let $p$ be the percentage you decrement by $n$ times and let $a_0$ be the starting value.

In the example you give, you've essentially defined the first few terms of a sequence recursively. We can expand on that and define the sequence generally. We have
$$
\begin{align}
a_t&=a_{t-1}-\left(\frac{p}{100}\right)a_{t-1}\\
a_t&=a_{t-1}\left(1-\frac{p}{100}\right).
\end{align}
$$

You want to find a closed-form expression (a formula) for $a_n$ so that you don't have to calculate each term preceding the result you want.

The key is noticing that this is a geometric sequence with $(1-\frac{p}{100})$ as its common ratio. The closed-form of a geometric sequence is well-known:
$$
a_n=a_0\left(1-\frac{p}{100}\right)^{n}.
$$

Comment: Thank you......